# Connection timeout on EC2 instance hosted Meteor App: how can I get more information?

Tags: meteor, amazon-ec2

I deployed using MUP an app on EC2. Deployment worked fine, `mup logs -n 300` returns normal server logs. This is all green, except I can't reach my server ip address over http. The connection times out.

Note that everything works fine too when I run my web app locally in production mode.

I can `mup start` and `mup stop` successfully.

What could I do to get more information on what is happening?

EDIT: I noticed my mup log ends with:

```
stepping down to gid: meteoruser
stepping down to uid: meteoruser
```

To quote MUP author, Arunoda Susiripala:

> Above is not an issue. It's some logs saying your app's permission has
>   been downgraded to an user called 'meteoruser'

Comment: Have you set the EC2 rule to allow http access to everyone?

Comment: I must check that with the client, who set up the instance. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @PhilipPryde you was right, my client forgot to set the http rules in the security group settings. Please write it as an answer, I'll validate it.

Comment: done. Glad you got it sorted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the http access rules in EC2 to ensure they are accessible from the client